# Ksoap2 Send Soap Request with Complex Object in Android

Tags: java, android, soap, android-ksoap2

My xml has to be like this:

```
    <d4p1:Criteria>
      <d4p1:DestinationTelcoCenter i:nil="true" />
    </d4p1:Criteria>
    <d4p1:MyAccountName>m_sobati</d4p1:MyAccountName>
    <d4p1:PagingInfo>
      <d4p1:PageNo>1</d4p1:PageNo>
      <d4p1:PageSize>10</d4p1:PageSize>
    </d4p1:PagingInfo>
    <d4p1:SortingInfo>
      <d4p1:Direction>ASC</d4p1:Direction>
      <d4p1:FieldName i:nil="true" />
    </d4p1:SortingInfo>
```

I have to create this `XML`. I try do it with `Ksoap2`. But it doesn't work. How can I handle this?

Comment: What error show here.

Comment: i want to create something like my xml that show above. because it is complex object i cant do it. ksoap2 has addProperty(), but in my case it is not correct way.

Comment: Post your code.